# Grouping patients and showing repeat visits

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a table called `Visits`:

```
ID(PKey,Int)
PatiendID(int),
DoctorID(int),
ExpectedDate(date),
ActualDate(date),
```

How can I write a query that for each patient returns the numbers of repeat visits.

The visit is considered to be repeated if it is less then half of the year from previous visit.

In other words I need for each patient find number of visits between (**last visit**-6 months) and last visit excluding last visit. Is it possible to write a query without cursors?

And other question. I have Table Patients

`ID(int, PKey),Name,Pasport,State`

Is it possible for each client from here find the same information? Or it is better union the query below and all clients that are not in visits table?

Comment: We need a few more requirements here.  Do you want _all_ 'repeated' visits, ever, or only those patients who have a 'repeated' visit recently?  If a visit is 'repeated' (within the 6 months), should it be allowed to count for other visits - that is, if a patient visits 3 times, once every 5 months, how many visits are there?  And what about a patient who visits regularily, every 2 months (indefinitely far in the past) - how should those be counted?

Comment: I want to get count of repeated visits, and of cause all not recent. I need simply to count number of visits that has taken place within six month from last visit. And that is for each patient. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words I need for each patient find number of visits between
>   (last visit-6 months) and last visit excluding last visit.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT PatientID, MAX(ActualDate) AS LastVisit
    FROM Visits
    GROUP BY PatientID
)
SELECT CTE.PatientID, COUNT(1)-1 AS RepeatVisits
FROM CTE INNER JOIN Visits ON CTE.PatientID = Visits.PatientID
WHERE ActualDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, LastVisit) AND LastVisit
GROUP BY CTE.PatientId
```

This will group, by patient, all visits in the six months before the last visit.  It will give you the COUNT (total) minus one (excluding the last visit).

Complete example:  http://pastebin.com/vpCdASpB

For the second part (Patients table), see here:  http://pastebin.com/nKw0Wqvp

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Patients.PatientID, Patients.Name, MAX(ActualDate) AS LastVisit
    FROM Patients LEFT JOIN Visits ON #patient.PatientID = Visits.PatientID
    GROUP BY Patients.PatientID, Patients.Name
)
SELECT CTE.PatientID, CTE.Name, COUNT(1)-1 AS RepeatVisits
FROM CTE LEFT JOIN Visits ON CTE.PatientID = Visits.PatientID
                          AND Visits.ActualDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -6, LastVisit) AND LastVisit
GROUP BY CTE.PatientId, CTE.Name
ORDER BY PatientID;
```

Comment: +1 very nice. I deleted my original answer which took a much more simplistic view of the requirements.

Comment: Two questions: I need all patients to be shown (with 0 visits as well). Plus why here we use group by?

Comment: seeker - Have you tried the query above?  My test shows that it will have all patients in it, even those that haven't had any visits in the past six months.  Also, the GROUP BY provides the ability to do a COUNT - read more here:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to get list of clients id not from visits table (where date is) but from other table (clients that has field ID) and execute the same query?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the details of your Client table, and I will modify my answer once I have that information.

Comment: Actually, re-reading your comment, I'm not sure I understand the Clients question.  Could you please provide more details in your question edit?

Comment: What exactly should  I Provide. I have table patients(clients,nomatter). Is it possible for each patient in patients find number of repeat visits in visits table? ID in clients table corresponds to PatientID in visits table. Thank you.

Comment: Let me reexplain again. I have table called patients (with ID field for identification purposes). How can i find for each client here the count of repeat visits in dbo.Visits table? the query above creates and delete temporary tables what is forbidden. Could you advice anything to me? Big thank you.

Comment: seeker - The query above is a complete solution that demonstrates the functionality of the SELECT.  Replace #tmp with Visits and #patient with your patients table.

Comment: With one exception: if patient(meaning it's ID) exists in patients table and does not exists in Visits table, result set doesn't contain such patient

Comment: Or, even better:  http://pastebin.com/nKw0Wqvp  Put it all into the join rather than bothering with the WHERE.